# Django save a model instance when testing but can't find it in real database

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing

I'am new to Django, when I was doing testing, I created a new test model record in setup() function for the following test, it succeeded, and I can access the record in the following code, but when I go to check the real database, the new record is not exist.

the setup code like this:

```
class UserTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        test_user = User.object.create(name='test')
```

when I set the breakpoint in the setUp() function, and after the 'test_user' is created, I can use 'User.object.get()' to obtain the created user, but when I go to real database and check the User table, I can't find this record. By the way, I use postgreSQL.

The test runner is using this:

```
class NoDBTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        pass
    def teardown_databases(self, old_config, **kwargs):
        pass
```

I want to know where the created data record is stored?
Any suggestion will be very helpful

Comment: Django uses a separate db for testing, which is created and destroyed when you run the tests.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for you answer. I can access other real data stored in real pg database in the following test function, if django create a separate temporary db for the 'test_user' record, it means django test module use both the real pg database and the separate temp db to serve my test code? If django can't find the record in real pg db, it will go to the separate db created by itself, is it right?

Answer (score 2):

Django Unit Tests create a separate database for testing. The main database is not used to avoid errors that may result from testing.

Comment: thanks, but django will create separate db even if I use NoDBTestRunner runner?

Comment: @JaydenFoo Where did you get `NoDBTestRunner` from? It doesn't appear to be part of Django core. As the name suggests, it will not create a database, but it will probably also not use your "real" database.

Comment: @Kal I defined the NoDBTestRunner myself, overwriting DiscoverRunner. It's very weird that I use wireshark to grab the packages and found that django actually send the "INSERT" command to the remote database, and the remote db reply the message showing the insert is succeed, but when I check the remote db, I can't find the new inserted record.

Comment: @JaydenFoo Did you check the remote db *after* the tests have finished running? If so, it may be because the test cases are automatically wrapped in transactions that are automatically rolled back at the end of the tests.

And depending on the transaction isolation level, you may be unable to find the rows even in the middle of the test run, if you, e.g., open a new connection session to the db.

Comment: @Kal Yes, after you suggestion, I found that all the action were wrapped in a transactions and after the test it will rollback to the initial checkpoints. Thanks!!